# How to fill cell reference down column without changing cell reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column of cells, all of which I want to equal the value in another cell.  I highlight the cell and type = and then do that again below, and then I highlight the cells and drag down but the column of cells equals a parallel column of values.  I want it to fix to one cell.  Does this make sense?  I'm sure it's easy but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the cell you want to reference is A3, make your formula:  `=$A$3`

The dollar signs make the cell reference absolute, so they won't be adjusted relative to where you paste.

Comment: As an addition to this you can use the "F4" key to cycle through the locking modes that excel supports (of which "$A$3" is one) to get $A3 which locks the data to column A but allows a copied cell to change across rows, A$3 which allows the data to change across columns but locks the row to 3, and $A$3 which locks both column and row when the cell is copied.  Pressing F4 repeatedly cycles through these modes and eventually you get back to the A3 "Normal" mode.  At least this is how it used to work, not got a copy of Office to hand to find out at the moment.